# Increase JavaScript Heap size in create-react-app project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, v8, create-react-app

Node features the way to increase the heap size via passing in the `--max-old-space-size` command line flag.
In create-react-app projects everything depends on the use of react-scripts.
How can I pass in this parameter in such projects and where should I best do that?

Thank you for help.

Comment: Since those scripts are just JS files in a special directory you should be able to call the Node process like you usually do, and pass `node_modules/.bin/react-scripts` as the argument to it. It is symlinked to the actual script.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Thanks a lot to @dan-abramov as his comment is the answer! (Give him the vote up in case you come across this).

You can just put e.g. `node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/.bin/react-scripts start` in there instead of `react-scripts start`

Comment: This is giving an error : basedir=$(dirname.......) line 2 of react scripts. It says missing ) after argument list. PLease help

Comment: I have same issue, Our ubuntu server ram 1GB so what i need to do ?

Comment: For smal servers you need put less memory. To me works with --max_old_space_size=256

Comment: what is 4096 here 4096 GB?

Comment: This is 4096 MB so 4 GB

Comment: this doesn't work for me, it still uses over 1gb of ram (when I set it to 256) and the processor goes to 300+%. Am I missing something? Is there any other way to constrain resource usage?

Comment: Getting `FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

Answer (score 29):

```
"build": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=4096 build"
```

This should work

Comment: what is 4096 here 4096 GB or MB?

Comment: @vinayakshahdeo it means 4096 MB

Comment: I tried this and didn't work for me even after setting 8 Gb or 12 Gb

Comment: Getting `FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

Comment: @fabpico ,
I also ended up with the same FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector
How did you resolve it?

Comment: @Sandeepsandy I think I fixed all `heap out of memory` ocurrances by upgrading NodeJs.

Answer (score 21):

You can disable generation of source maps as described in https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration

Indeed as per the documentation:

> When set to false, source maps are not generated for a production
>   build. This solves out of memory (OOM) issues on some smaller
>   machines.

Which is the case when you got an Heap Out Of Memory error

To do so, create a .env file and add `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false`

Answer (score 11):

One line answer, run on terminal -> `export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `craco build` just add the flag in like the below

```
craco --max_old_space_size=4096 build
```

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
ENV GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false
```

in your docker file.
This worked for me.

Thanks!