# Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

When I run my app in development everything is fine but we I build the project for production using "npm run build" , I get this error:

```
2.9b72e8af.chunk.js:sourcemap:1 Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype 
may only be an Object or null: undefined
at setPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
at t (2.9b72e8af.chunk.js:sourcemap:1)
at 2.9b72e8af.chunk.js:sourcemap:1
at 2.9b72e8af.chunk.js:sourcemap:1
at Object.<anonymous> (2.9b72e8af.chunk.js:sourcemap:1)
at l ((index):1)
at Object.<anonymous> (2.9b72e8af.chunk.js:sourcemap:1)
at l ((index):1)
at Object.<anonymous> (2.9b72e8af.chunk.js:sourcemap:1)
at l ((index):1)
```

First I got Heap error that I resolved it by adding:

"start": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=4096 start",

"build": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=4096 build",

From this post:

[How to fix "FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55613789/how-to-fix-fatal-error-ineffective-mark-compacts-near-heap-limit-allocation-fa/56779651)

I read few other posts that had the same issue like mine but none of them helped.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to post the code that causes the error, as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it was because of the bug from the Dialog component of Syncfusion and they provided a patch for that.