# Next.js application run problem by FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am working with Next.js but after work sometimes I face this problem. Can't run my project.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55613789/how-to-fix-fatal-error-ineffective-mark-compacts-near-heap-limit-allocation-fa)

Answer (score 0):

- You need to [install](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/) the latest Node version or use a Node Version Manager to switch to the version you want.
- If you use Maven plugin you need in your pom.xml to change the node_version to the version you use and re-run again deploy command you are using. Example of the pom.xml lines you need to change:

> ```
> <configuration>
>      <nodeVersion>v16.11.1</nodeVersion>
>      <npmVersion>6.9.0</npmVersion>
> </configuration>
> ```