# Create react app deployment in digital ocean - App stuck at 'starting development server'

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, digital-ocean, digital-ocean-apps

I recently hosted my app on the Digital ocean App platform. I connected my git hub page, and the build succeeded.

But when I open a site, it throws me an error.
[Live page error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hq42t.png)
It responds with 504 error

When I checked the logs App platform, it was stuck at 'Starting development server.'

```
[frontend-waffle-frontend] [2022-11-25 06:52:57] 
[frontend-waffle-frontend] [2022-11-25 06:52:57] > frontend@0.1.0 start
[frontend-waffle-frontend] [2022-11-25 06:52:57] > react-scripts --max_old_space_size=4096 start
[frontend-waffle-frontend] [2022-11-25 06:52:57] 
[frontend-waffle-frontend] [2022-11-25 06:53:07] (node:24) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_AFTER_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onAfterSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
[frontend-waffle-frontend] [2022-11-25 06:53:07] (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
[frontend-waffle-frontend] [2022-11-25 06:53:07] (node:24) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_BEFORE_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onBeforeSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.



[frontend-waffle-frontend] [2022-11-25 06:53:08] Starting the development server...
[frontend-waffle-frontend] [2022-11-25 06:53:08]
```

I tried many ways to address the issue, but no solution has been found till now. Can any of you guys encounter this before?
Please help me out!

I tried force building and cleared the cache for the build on the Digital ocean app platform. Nothing works!
Please provide me with a solution if you have one.

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: I resolved this issue,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72628009/16723837.
This solved my issue, and I am thankful for this one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55613789/how-to-fix-fatal-error-ineffective-mark-compacts-near-heap-limit-allocation-fa)

Answer (score 0):

Try add `"homepage": ""` at your package.json file. Had the same problem, this solution helped me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).