# `react-scripts build' is using 1+ GB of RAM

Tags: reactjs, build, react-scripts

I have a relatively simple React 15 website. It only has a few distinct pages, and it's mainly just text and some pictures. However, when I use `react-scripts build` to build the project for production deployment, I'm finding that the node process tops out at around **1.25 GB** of RAM used. This hasn't been an issue when building on my workstation, but it's a problem on my production server, where I currently only have **1 GB** of RAM available. Most of the time, the server kills my build due to running out of memory.

So it seems my options are to spend more money to upgrade to **2GB** of RAM on the server, or find some way to reduce the memory usage. I'd like to avoid paying more, because normally I don't use more than **200 MB** of RAM to run my application, and it's just building it that uses a lot of RAM.

I've seems some people recommend adding a `--max-old-space-size=` flag to the build, but that doesn't seem to do anything. That is, I've tried this in my package.json:

```
"build": "react-scripts --max-old-space-size=512 build"
```

But it still uses up **1+ GB** of RAM. I kick off the build via `npm run build`, and adding the `--max-old-space-size` flag to that `npm` command doesn't seem to do anything.

Is there anything I can do to prevent the `react-scripts` build process from using so much memory?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem yet?

Comment: No, I couldn't find a solution to this. I just ended up increasing the RAM on my VM, and moved on with things.

Comment: I also assumed using `--max-old-space-size` would fix it but it doesn't. The only option I see is to go the usual CI route and build it on a separate machine and push the built files to the instance

Comment: is it possible that you are generating source maps when building a production build? I had this situation (it needed around 1.4GB) when accidentally i enabled source maps generation

Comment: Perhaps related https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8096

Comment: Try to use Webpack bundle analyzer to check your npm packages maybe you have installed too many and too heavy

Comment: Does this help you: https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html

Answer (score 7):

The answer from [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046366/increase-javascript-heap-size-in-create-react-app-project):

You can just put `--max_old_space_size` for node process instead of react-script.

e.g. `node --max_old_space_size=512 node_modules/.bin/react-scripts build`

Answer (score 3):

1. You could add [`swap`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq) space on your production server. Please refer to [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-18-04)
2. What `node` version are you using on the production server?
   Try to upgrade your `node` version using [`nvm` or other ways](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/update-node-js-version). I think it is a problem for you.

Comment: This doesn't work. I added swap space (3GiB) over 1 GiB of RAM. It still runs out of memory. My node version is v16.15.1, and that doesn't help either.

Answer (score 2):

In `Package.json` file modify the build script as below.

```
"build": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=4096 build"
```

This should work!

Additionally in `.env` file you can specify not to generate source map for your project it will help your App to load faster!

```
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false
```

Comment: Great idea, but you can't debug your react app if you disable source map

Comment: The `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` helps a lot, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar issue, but in my case, it helped me when I updated
the react-scripts package that comes with CRA (create-react-app).

If your current version is 3.x.x upgrade it to the latest version of 3, you can find all the available version from here.

v3.x.x - https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/CHANGELOG-3.x.md

v2.x.x - https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/CHANGELOG-2.x.md