# Are my server resources enough for running `create-react-app`?

Tags: reactjs, server, create-react-app, digital-ocean, vps

I tried setting up a ReactJS app with `create-react-app` on my DigitalOcean Droplet with 10 GB disk space and 512 MB RAM (Ubuntu 22.04), though it keeps failing on `react-scripts`. When I do it on my much better equipped local machine (also Ubuntu), it works fine. Any idea what might cause this?

Answer (score 1):

It might be due to the available RAM. Following what was tried in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57762452/react-scripts-build-is-using-1-gb-of-ram):

```
node --max_old_space_size=512 node_modules/.bin/react-scripts build
```

Comment: Is there a way of specifying this for create-react-app? Because I don’t want to do it manually

Comment: Try "build": "react-scripts --max-old-space-size=512 build" in your package.json.

Comment: Alright, but there is no package.json before executing create-react-app. Should I just run npm init?

Comment: Hmm, no. The idea is to have the json and files generated by create-react-app. One workaround I can think of is running create-react-app on your local, changing the build command over there, push everything into a remote repo and simply clone it in the server.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that, too, but wasn't sure if create-react-app does anything outside the folder, like edit some configuration with a wider scope

Comment: But if all create-react-app does is generate the directory and file structure, then I may as well edit the build command on the remote machine, too, right?

Answer (score 1):

export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=512

npx create-react-app my-app

Comment: This doesn't make a difference, unfortunately