# How can I prevent React and Plotly crashing the development server due to JavaScript heap out of memory?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows-subsystem-for-linux, plotly.js, wsl-2

I am trying to build a create-react-app with react-plotly.js but when the plot components are included the compiler hangs and eventually fails displaying the error:

`FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

I checked the node heap limit using this command:

`` node -e 'console.log(`node heap limit = ${require("v8").getHeapStatistics().heap_size_limit / (1024 * 1024)} Mb`)' ``

which returned:

`node heap limit = 1456.1747760772705 Mb`

I am using the WSL 2 Linux subsystem for Windows.

I have tried editing the package.json and replacing `react-scripts start`
with `node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/.bin/react-scripts start` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046366/increase-javascript-heap-size-in-create-react-app-project) but the error was the same. I have also tried reducing it and using 512 as I have read that is sometimes advised if there is not enough space on the machine.

Any ideas how I can get this to work?

Comment: Interestingly, I can seem to get React Plotly to work in a Gatsby project.

Answer (score 1):

I had success resolving this issue by disabling the GENERATE_SOURCEMAP flag in my .env file, ie

```
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false
```

as suggested by the (slightly unrelated) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57892656).