# who i can change the memory consuming limit on a react application?

Tags: reactjs, memory, limit

My react application are consuming high memory. I saw that the command `node --max-old-space-size` can limit the memory use, but how i can set this configuration to my react app?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing - react runs in a browser, and node on the server side. The answer may depend on what you are using for your application as a server. Or do you mean that build is failing? Then this may be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046366/increase-javascript-heap-size-in-create-react-app-project

Comment: well, when i run my application on development mode `npm start`, the node process associate consume high memory;

Comment: @Nikolay its really the some problem. Thaks for your help